# What is the best way to escape quotes via Groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, smtp, jenkins-plugins

How do I fix the url syntax for the below script?

I'm attempting to run this in a Jenkins job and receive the below bold error.
I tried adding backspace before quote to escape and even surround double quotes with single quotes.  What am i doing wrong?
**org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 8: expecting anything but ''\n''; got it anyway @ line 8, column 190.
" -SmtpServer "smtp.gmail.com"**

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage("Using curl example") {
        steps {
            script {
                final String url = "Send-MailMessage -From me@gmail.com -To you@gmail.com -Subject "Send Test Message to Mailout Relay" -Body "Test Message" -SmtpServer "smtp.gmail.com"

                final String response = sh(script: "curl -s $url", returnStdout: true).trim()

                echo response
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use triple quoted string. `""" abc = "xyz" """` or escape every special char with backslash `\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have, at least, 2 options:

Use single quotes inside the double quotes (replace the `final String url` line with this one):

```
final String url = "Send-MailMessage -From me@gmail.com -To you@gmail.com -Subject 'Send Test Message to Mailout Relay' -Body 'Test Message' -SmtpServer 'smtp.gmail.com'"
```

or escape the double quotes inside the string:

```
final String url = "Send-MailMessage -From me@gmail.com -To you@gmail.com -Subject \"Send Test Message to Mailout Relay\" -Body \"Test Message\" -SmtpServer \"smtp.gmail.com\""
```